# Asp.Net Mvc Edit User profile with user Role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-roles

Why is my Action in Asp.Net Mvc code crashing when I want to get current user Role Name, when I want to edit user profile?
This code is crashing

```
model.ApplicationRoleId = roleManager.Roles.Single(r => r.Name == userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result.Single()).Id;
```

Error message I get is : 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here is my EditUserview

```
public class EditUserViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationRoleId { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> DepartmentNames { get; set; }

    public int DeptId { get; set; }   // I have DeptId too in my AspNetUser table
}
```

And my Edituser action

```
    [HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditUser(string id)
{
    EditUserViewModel model = new EditUserViewModel();
    model.ApplicationRoles = roleManager.Roles.Select(r => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = r.Name,
        Value = r.Id
    }).ToList();

    model.DepartmentNames = context.Departments.Select(s => new SelectListItem
    {

        Text = s.DeptName,
        Value = s.DeptId.ToString()
    }).ToList();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (user != null)
        {
            model.Name = user.Name;
            model.Email = user.Email;
            model.DeptId = user.DepartmentId;
           //model.ApplicationRoleId crashing
            model.ApplicationRoleId = roleManager.Roles.Single(r => r.Name == userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result.Single()).Id; // Here crashing .. I don't know why.. Server 500 error

            ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(RoleManager.Roles, "Id", "Name", model.ApplicationRoleId);
            ViewBag.DeptId = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Deptd", "DeptName", model.DeptId);


        }
    }
    return PartialView("_EditUser", model);
}
```

I tried like this but even this crashing ..

```
string existingRole = UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id).Result.Single();// This crashing
```

then to put here :

```
string existingRoleId = RoleManager.Roles.Single(r => r.Name == existingRole).Id;
```

but string existingRole  didn't work for me..

I would be greateful for any help..

Comment: You should not call the async method using `Result`. await your method like `var r=await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id); var existingRole=u.First();` Also use Single method when you are sure that your collection will always have only one item, otherwise it will throw an `InvalidOperationException` exception.

Comment: @Shyju thank you for your response, but what do you mean var r=await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);? Where to put this result? Do you mean model.ApplicationRoleId = wait UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);? And then var existingRole=u.First() ? where is coming u? u must declare somewhere..  .. I mean what should I initialaize  my model.ApplicationRoleId? .Thank you again.

Comment: @Shyju , can you please help..?.

Answer (score 0):

I did like this as @Shyju wrote

```
 var role = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
                        var existingRole = role.First();
     if (existingRole != null)
      {
     string existingRoleId = RoleManager.Roles.Single(r => r.Name == existingRole).Id;
    model.ApplicationRoleId = existingRoleId;
    .....  and so on ....

   }
```

Thank you  @Shyju